# MPMoviePlayerController on iPhone 3.0 SDK

Tags: iphone, video, sdk

Did Apple change anything about the MPMoviePlayerController class on the iPhone 3.0 SDK? My app no longer pops up a video when I tap the correct button, no error popup or anything.

Answer (score 1):

Nothing has changed from what I can see by comparing the 2.1 and 3.0 documentation for MPMoviePlayerController.

Answer (score 1):

I noticed this in my app too. But then it started working again after some time without any changes! Nothing from the Apple documentation suggests that they've made any changes.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure nothing has changed recently in your nib file?

Did you verify your action method is being called when you press the button?